# yesod persistent dependencies missing

Tags: yesod

I have tried to follow the Yesod quick start from the official website, but when running `yesod devel` (after installation and running `yesod init`) it fails to build due to a missing dependency if I use sqlite, postgresql, postgresql+fay or mysql (the 'simple' option from `yesod-init` works fine).

The error messages given are:

For sqlite:

```
cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
persistent-sqlite ==1.3.*
```

For postgresql:

```
cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
persistent-postgresql ==1.3.*
```

For postgres + fay:

```
cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
fay >=0.16, persistent-postgresql ==1.3.*, yesod-fay >=0.5.0.1
```

For mysql:

```
cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
persistent-mysql  ==1.3.*
```

For mongoDB:

```
cabal: At least the following dependencies are missing:
persistent-mongoDB ==1.3.*
```

Does anyone know what is going wrong and how it can be fixed?

Update:

I was able to fix some of the problems by installing, separately from the yesod-platform, some of the missing dependencies.

`cabal install persistent-sqlite` fixed any problems using sqlite.

`cabal install persistent-postgresql` and `cabal install persistent-mysql` worked after installing some extra distribution packages to my Mint 16 system (libpq-dev and libmysqlclient-dev).

`cabal install persistent-mongodb` failed with an error I could not resolve:

Resolving dependencies...
Configuring persistent-mongoDB-1.3.1...
Building persistent-mongoDB-1.3.1...
Preprocessing library persistent-mongoDB-1.3.1...
[1 of 1] Compiling Database.Persist.MongoDB ( Database/Persist/MongoDB.hs, dist/build/Database/Persist/MongoDB.o )

Database/Persist/MongoDB.hs:420:26:
    Not in scope: type constructor or class `MonadThrow'
Failed to install persistent-mongoDB-1.3.1
cabal: Error: some packages failed to install:
persistent-mongoDB-1.3.1 failed during the building phase. The exception was:
ExitFailure 1

Does anybody know how to resolve this issue?

Update:

This final problem has been solved by the maintainer updating the cabal package.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is a new version without this error (I have installed persistent-mongoDB-1.3.1.1, the previous version had the error you found).

Do a `cabal update` to refresh the packages list and try again.